# Imagen desde imageList a Picturebox sale borrosa (c#)

Tags: c#, imagen, picturebox

Estoy tratando de insertar una imagen desde un ImageList hasta un PictureBox, pero, cuando cargo la imagen, esta sale muy borrosa, el código es este: 
P3.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[0];
[image: Debería salir totalmente nítida]

Debería salir nítida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a la comunidad brother, lamento informarte que ImageList está diseñado para imágenes pequeñas, como iconos por ejemplo.

Por lo que no es funcional para imagenes grandes; el tamaño por default de ImageList es de 16x16 pixeles y tiene un máximo de 256x256 por lo que si insertas una imagen mayor pierde calidad y la transforma a 256x256 (proporcional)

Espero esta respuesta te haya servido; también te puedo recomendar utiliar un `List<>` para crear tus listas desde el código.

Por ejemplo podrías tener un `List<String>` en donde almacenas el path de las imágenes.

Por cierto, si mi respuesta te ayudo, puedes votar por ella ;)